# npm run build with folder path having spaces

Tags: angular, npm-build

Trying to do CI\CD with TFSVC classic editor
I tried npm tasks (install and build). But it errors.
Any best resources to use. On build agent server, node js is installed on D drive.
First tried in azure dev ops service CI pipeline.
Then tried to make sure about syntax, tried locally testing.

```
C:\> cd Testing Angular
    c:\Testing Angular>cd node_modules
    c:\Testing Angular\node_modules>cd .bin
    c:\Testing Angular\node_modules\.bin>npm run build C:\"Testing Angular"
```

Error: Project 'C:"Testing' does not exist

Comment: npm run build "C:\\Testing Angular" ? 

would be a double backslash for the \ and a double-quoted parameter at all with all the path on it